# React - Log in submit button to render new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, components

I am very new to react and I'm stuck on how to render a new componant when a user logs in.

I first want to display a log in page (which just requires text and pressing submit) once submit has been pressed I would like it to load a new page so the user no longer sees the login box.

I currently have a form and when the user presses submit the new page I would like to display renders below the current login rather than replacing it, how would I go about changing this please?

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import LoggedIn from './LoggedIn ';

class LogIn extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: '',
    showComponent: false,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this._handleSubmit = this._handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  _handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showComponent: true,
    });
  }

render() {
return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>Enter your username to continue</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Username:
                    <input type="text" name="UserId" value={this.state.value} onChange= 
{this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
    {this.state.showComponent ?
       <LoggedIn /> :
       null
    }
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
}

export default LogIn;
```

Logged in component is current just a blank page with the text 'test'

```
import React from 'react';

function LoggedIn() {
    return (
        <div>
           <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default LoggedIn;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) to setup routes and go to your test page when submit button is clicked from log in page,

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Login from "./Login";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

you can see my sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-thunder-7lozn?file=/src/App.js:0-433)

Comment: Brilliant Thanks for this and the code sample - very helpful! @Kaung Khant Zaw

Comment: Not sure if you could help please? If I wanted to pass the username to /home as a prop how would I do this please? SO i can display something like "welcome <username>"

Comment: You can pass state as second parameter in `history.replace()` method so it will be `history.replace('/home', value)`. And then get props in your home component `export default function Home(props) {..}` and call the state as `props.location.state` in your `jsx`

Comment: Thank you again I really appreciate your help!